# Dialog flow CX web crawling

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am trying to do web crawling using Dialog flow CX to implement FAQ bot which can form Question and answer pair, but I am unable to find any kind of option in it. Can anyone help me out to know if this functionality is present in Dialog flow cx as of now

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding I hope you're looking to use the Generative AI features in DialogFlow CX. This feature consists of the qna system by uploading the web page URLs. According to the [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/release-notes) DialogFlow CX does not support such features currently. If you want this feature in dialogflow cx you can create a new feature request in the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). You can try using the webhooks feature of dialog flow cx to add web crawling feature. For more information about webhooks you can to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an agent in Dialogflow CX you can create a data store from your website or documents (you will find the data store section in the Manage tab of Dialogflow) and then add it to the conversation page you want in the Build tab of Dialogflow.

If you are starting your project and do not have a Dialogflow agent yet, you can use Vertex AI Conversation (before called Gen App Builder). In a few clicks you will have a new Dialogflow CX agent with a data store that can answer to the info of the website or the documents that you provided in the creation process.

If you are working with documents, such as pdf, you need to have them in a bucket. If you want the agent to answer questions about a website you can provide the url of the website and Vertex AI Conversation will do the Webcrawling for you and build the data store with all the information. You must take into account that you must be the owner of the website for the webcrawling.

Once the Dialogflow CX agent with the data store is created it's better to wait a little bit before testing it, since the datastore can need some time to be ready for querying, specially if it contains a lot of information.

Here you can read about Vertex AI Conversation:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/vertex-ai-search-and-conversation-is-now-generally-available

And here a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpkdsTE4ekA

And this is the documentation of Generative agents in Dialogflow CX: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/generative-agent